# SSL Handshake in Java Servlet (HttpsURLConnection)

Tags: java, servlets, ssl

I have a java web application that requires a servlet to open a connection with a url that returns some data in the form of JSON back to the servlet for processing. Traditionally this was done using an HttpURLConnection and everything worked as planned.

Now, we have added as self-signed SSL certificate to the server in which we are making the connection to for the JSON data. My question is simply how to go about making this new HTTPS connection. Just to note, when the application is actually deployed it will be making connections the legitimate SSL certificates.

Here is sample code for how the HttpURLConnection was working before the self-signed SSL certificate.

```
    URL url = new URL("HTTP SERVER URL GOES HERE");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

And here is how I changed it for the HTTPS connection:

```
    URL url = new URL("HTTPS SERVER URL GOES HERE");
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I assumed that this would be a simple change seeing as how I can request the URL (the one that returns my JSON data) in the web browser. Why does this not work in Java?

I receive an SSLHandshakeException when trying to make the request:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching "SERVER HERE" found
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, whenever SSL connection is established it tries to verify the server name with the host name in certificate. In this case, since it is self signed it may not be having any server name mostly.

What you need to do is write a implementation of  `javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier` and assign to your `HttpsURLConnection`.

This HostnameVerifier can be written to always return true or based on whatever condition you like.

```
final HostnameVerifier hv=new HostnameVerifier(){
     public boolean verify(    final String arg0,    final SSLSession arg1){
     return true;
    }
}
```

And, assign to the HttpsURLConnection like this:

```
URL url = new URL("HTTPS SERVER URL GOES HERE");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

Comment: After trying this solution this error was generated:                              javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Ohh, the cert has to be in your trusted certs i.e, in the client trusted certs.

Comment: Do you know how to do that.

Comment: What is the best way to go about accomplishing that, I am new to SSL and its slightly overwhelming.

Comment: Ok, what server are using? The server configuration might somewhere define the trust store path. Later, you have to import this self signed cert into that trust store.

Comment: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/22737/import-certificate-into-the-trust-store explains to some extent.

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat, I have it simply running through the eclipse IDE. I will check out that link and see if I can't figure this out.

Comment: Hrm, cannot seem to figure this one out. Is this something that gets stored on the tomcat server? I have the certificate but don't know where to put it.

Comment: look at server.xml , you should see <Connector
    port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    keystoreFile="C:\mykeystore.jks"
    keystorePass="mykeystore"
    truststoreFile="C:\mykeystore.jks"
    truststorePass="mykeystore"
/>. Add your cert to trustsotrefile.

Comment: If the truststore is not present it would be using the jre lib default trust store.

Comment: Took me a little bit of time but I got it!! Thanks very much!